# Is it ok to put insulation on attic floor?

Tags: insulation

[image]

Discovered that the walls are not insulated, and that the drywall ceiling simply rests on the walls and is nailed to the joists above. Plan is to insulate walls, but will need to frame them out, and to add insulation to the attic (currently rodent-invested blown in fiberglass). Ceiling above ugly drop ceiling is in bad shape. My thought is to expose the joists and stain them for a decorative look since I have to put the work into taking the ceiling down anyway. But I'm not sure if it's ok to put insulation on top of the plywood. Thoughts?

Comment: If you are asking if it is okay to have just plywood (sitting on top of the joists) between the living space and the insulation, that should be fine. But then you have the exposed plywood between the beams on the ceiling (or are you going to paint that?) I would also recommend using rigid foam insulation with "great stuff" filling in the gaps between the rigid foam insulation and the joists (it will be a bit more expensive and some more work, but will be worth it for the much higher R-Value, especially if you live in a cold climate): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i1guAwzyEOQ

Comment: Thank you Dillon.  I've been working in the attic almost every night since Thanksgiving and have all the drywall down from the ceiling.  I'm thinking about a ply bead or planks.  Thank you for the rigid foam/great stuff suggestions. I'll look into it!